# Active Directory whenChanged attribute

Tags: microsoft-outlook, user-accounts, active-directory, attributes, shared-mailbox

i am a bit confused when it comes to the whenchanged user-attribute in active directory.
Lets say i have a user xy with a mailbox. This mailbox is shared with a few people.
They all do not log directly into this account, but via outlook.

Am i assuming right, that everytime a user is receiving an email with that account, the whenchanged attribute will change?

I know, that this attribute wont replicate to all the dcs but it would help me in my investigation if i fully understand this attribute.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Am i assuming right, that everytime a user is receiving an email with
>   that account, the whenchanged attribute will change?

The answer is... No.

This atributte only change when some information in the attributes of User in DA... !changed¡ ;) or you change a primary group. Recieve mails dont modify the object

For example, adress, phone number, password, etc.

For more information check this

http://www.morgantechspace.com/2014/11/whenChanged-and-modifyTimeStamp-in-Active-Directory.html